# Sqlite3 not working on heroku and changing to postgresql will not run migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

New to rails and web development and after working for 4 weeks on this project I just discovered that sqlite3 doesn't work on heroku. They have a tutorial on their webpage on how to change the database for my rails app from sqlite3 to postgresql. 
First I removed the `gem 'sqlite3'`and replaced it with `gem 'pg'`. 
Then I ran bundle install and changed `config/database.yml` From

```
    default: &default
      adapter: sqlite3
      pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
      timeout: 5000

   development:
     <<: *default
     database: db/development.sqlite3

   test:
     <<: *default
     database: db/test.sqlite3

   production:
     <<: *default
     database: db/production.sqlite3
```

To

```
      default: &default
      adapter: postgresql
      pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
      timeout: 5000

   development:
     <<: *default
     database: my_newapp_development

   test:
     <<: *default
     database: my_newapp_test

   production:
     <<: *default
     database: my_newapp_production
```

So after this I try running db:create but it says "could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? " on line "return PG::Connection.new( *args )". Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you install postgresql and is it running on your local machine?

Comment: hello, seems I didnt have postgresql installed. I am installing it now. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if postgresql is installed on your local machine using terminal.

`psql --version`

If installed, then check if the psql server is running or not.

`ps aux | grep postgresql`

To start postgres server, run the following command on terminal

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`